# AWS Secrets Manager and springboot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, aws-secrets-manager, spring-cloud-aws

I am trying to use AWS Secrets Manager to store secrets for a springboot microservice. I was able to configure everything and I can see that on startup the application is loading the secret that in my case is a json document. In particular I am using

```
'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws-secrets-manager-config:2.2.1.RELEASE'
```

Since I noticed that AwsSecretsManagerPropertySource was able to parse the response json into a Map of Objects I tried to use a nested structure for my secret but if I tried to inject any field of the json using the @Value annotation is failing with a conversion exception.
So, if my secret is a json with only string as fields I am able to inject them. For example:

```
{
"a.b":"value"
...
}
```

using

```
@Value("${a.b}")
String field;
```

it´s working fine but if I have a secret like

```
{
"a": {
  "b":"value"
}
```

I saw that the json is successfully parsed but using the annotation

```
@Value("${a.b}")
String field;
```

I am not able to retrieve a field and if I try something like

```
@Value("${a}")
Map<String, String> field;
```

it´s failing due to a conversion issue (unable to convert from a LinkedHashMap to a string).
Is there any way to handle a nested structure into a secret or should I just used a json with no nested objects?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

After few attempts, I was able to access the Maps/Lists I was retrieving from AWS Secret Manager injecting the ***Environment*** object into a configuration and calling:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfigurationClass {

  @Autowired
  Environment environment;

  @Bean 
  public MyBean myBean() {
     List sites = environment.getProperty("sites", List.class);
     ...
  }
```